# Update a table without using join

Tags: sql, sql-update, ddl

I have a table called employee
Empid Empname

1. ```
   price
   ```
2. ```
   Soap
   ```
3. ```
   Ryan
   ```

I want to add a new column and update the Empname to that new column like below:
Empid Empname Empname_New

1. ```
   Price  Price
   ```
2. ```
   Soap.  Soap
   ```
3. ```
   Ryan.  Ryan
   ```

Simple update statement is working for this:

Update employee set empname_new =Empname;

I am not able to understand how this update is working and how this update could create an error while executing for huge amount of data.

Comment: Which database engine do you use? MySQL, MS Sql Server, SQLite,...?

Comment: For a huge amount of data that query will take a long time to run. If you app has some time limit (say 5 mins) then the app could show an error, while the query is still running. In some databases it could even produce a table lock, and that could prevent other processes to run normally.